# Change previous commits messages while keep them signed-off

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-sign

I have a bunch of signed-off and pushed commits. I want to change their messages. However, when I do so with commands such as: `git rebase -i HEAD~12` and `reword` their signatures disappear (I check it with `git log --show-signature`). How to change commits messages while keeping them signed-off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to keep the old signatures while changing (e.g. its messages) the commits.

One way to change messages and sign-off again (creating new commits and substituting the old ones) is:

`git rebase -i -S HEAD~12`

Comment: This is because you literally *can't* change a commit. You can only make a *new* commit that you start using instead of the old one. So you must sign the new commit.

Answer (score 1):

You can sign them off again using this command:

```
git commit --amend --signoff
```

For multiple commits:

```
git filter-branch -f --commit-filter 'git commit-tree -S "$@"' HEAD
git push -f
```

Comment: use filter-branch for multiple commits. updated the answer